# Used iPhone 5 - What do I need to do to register as the new iPhone owner, have warranty, etc

Tags: iphone, warranty

Buying a used iPhone 5. What should be my next steps to register as the new iPhone owner in Apple's eyes, have warranty, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warranty is established by Apple based on the serial number and nothing else.

If you want to register things, you can do several things:

- Contact AppleCare http://www.apple.com/support/contact/ or via [phone](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE57)
- Self register at https://register.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/GlobaliReg.woa
- Self register by erasing all content and settings (via Settings App - Reset or iTunes restore) and opting in with an Apple ID to register the device.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your iPhone as a new device via iTunes on your computer and follow through the steps (log in to your Apple ID or create a new one). You will be given the opportunity to register your iPhone under your name.